# How can I install GMagick on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

I get this error when trying to run my application:

```
Heroku PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Gmagick' not found in /app/lib.php
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: ADMINS: This is not off-topic as it pertains to how to operate an application _on_ Heroku. If this was simply a PHP question, I'd be happy to send them to Stack Overflow instead. But not the case here.  

Comment: Are Heroku questions with no connection to the Salesforce platform on-topic? We don't seem to have a [conclusive answer](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/are-questions-about-heroku-on-or-off-topic).

Comment: Since Heroku is part of Salesforce, I would certainly say so. Quip follows this model for developer support as well: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quip Feel free to email me at jmccartie@salesforce.com to discuss further?

Comment: Didn't mean to put you on the spot, Jon, asking more generally since I was the first close vote and wondering whether the question was wrongly closed or rightly closed for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to install the graphicsmagick library? If so, you might want to check out this buildpack: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/xerpa/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick

Also, if you need a particular linux library, you can install with the [apt-get buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt)

Comment: I've tried several GraphicsMagick elements, I've also tried **apt-get buildpack** but how do I activate it in PHP, do I need settings on user.ini?

Comment: I followed up with our PHP team. It looks like that extension is not available. They suggest you use ImageMagick instead. http://php.net/manual/book.imagick You can see the full list of supported extensions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions